# I can't upgrade my ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04

I have a problem installing the 12.10, because it says that it isn't supported anymore

Comment: So it is not supported any more. You can upgrade 12.04 to 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

12.10 reached end of live in 2014-04-30. Update Manager and `do-release-update` should offer you to upgrade to 14.04, as that's the only supported upgrade path for 12.04 now.